# using dpdk rte_mp_request_sync to send a message to peer process

Tags: ipc, dpdk

My dpdk version is 20.11, I have 2 processes, one is primary, the other one is secondary, I want to send a message from primary process to secondary process, so I choose 'rte_mp_request_sync' help me to send it, but I found that secondary process can receive the message from primary, but it cannot use 'rte_mp_reply' to reply it. Even though I use 'rte_mp_reply' to reply that message, but nothing happened at primary.

Does anyone know why it doesn't work when secondary process reply message to primary process.

Primary send a message to secondary and wait for the reply.